# Flutter Command not working properly with the error showing Could not find an option named "suppress-analytics"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run a flutter app, and whenever I type flutter or flutter doctor, I get this message:

[image: Console log of Flutter error]

I have already installed Flutter and added the path to environment variable. I also have tried to download another Flutter SDK and also tried to update Dart.

Comment: What's the command you're using to build your app? Also, please show your output of flutter doctor -v

Comment: I'm writing the command flutter and flutter doctor which gives me this output:
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Could not find an option named "suppress-analytics".

Usage: dart pub upgrade [dependencies...]
-h, --help               Print this usage information.
    --[no-]offline       Use cached packages instead of accessing the network.
-n, --dry-run            Report what dependencies would change but don't change any.

Comment: @Jannik why not reinstall the OS while we are at it? Heck, OP, go buy a new computer!

Comment: What kind of OS is this and which version? Are you using any AV software? Is this a corporate pc?

Comment: My best guess is that this is a network issue, maybe an SSL problem, since `pub upgrade` uses `dart:io` and error 64 is probably a `SocketException` (https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/729). What happens if you `wget` this address: https://pub.dev/packages/bloc/versions/8.1.4.tar.gz